# save facebook photo to mysql BLOB

Tags: php, jquery, facebook, image, upload

Just a quick question I am wanting to allow users to link there facebook account to my new product, and I am wondering how do I take there facebook photo URL and save it as an image in BLOB formate for MYSQL

I am using this example to connect to Facebook
https://github.com/facebook/connect-js/blob/master/examples/jquery/login.html

and to send the image to my server I use the $.ajax formate to submit it to the core.php (I have not coded this yet, as I need to know the best way.

Answer (score 0):

Well my first recommandation is to NOT store image data in your database unless you absolutely need that in your database backups. You will clutter your database massively. Instead, just get the url to the picture using the server-side $facebook class, and just "file_get_contents" it to your php memory.

Then dump it on disk and save a reference of that dumped image in your database. It will do much more good to your database this way.

Else, if you really want to save it to a BLOB, use the same method to fetch the image to memory and then use the hex() function to transform it to a textual representation that can be fit into an INSERT/UPDATE query...

Answer (score 0):

Just save a reference to the location where Facebook stores the image. That way you can abuse their servers (which are very nice/fast) and just serve image tags that refer to their servers.

Also when you save images to a database you lose the native compression that you get when you save an image to the filesystem, so you bloat your data storage size for not much reason (backups are easier I suppose).